# Eclipse AWS Lambda Error : No Serverless.template found in your project root

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created AWS Lambda Project in Eclipse using Eclipse AWS Plugin's "New AWS Lambda Java Project".
The project is created successfully and I can perform mvn install as well.

However, when I right click and choose "Deploy Serverless Project", it shows an error box as below

```
No Serverless.template found in your project root
```

[image]

I am using Eclipse Luna.
Could anyone please help ? 
I searched on internet but didn't find any relevant answers.

Comment: did you ever find an answer? I am trying to convert a java project into a AWS Lambda project.

Comment: No. I gave up on that.

Comment: you know what's funny? you get a different set of choices if you right-click on the java class itself. Mine is now working.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider this is a bug with Eclipse AWS plugin, since this happens when you create a "Lambda Project", but try to deploy it as "Serverless Project".

To deploy your Lambda function, you can:

1. Right-click in lambda in your Project Explorer (or in code window)
2. Choose `Amazon Web Services`/`AWS Lambda`
3. Choose `Upload function to AWS Lambda`.

[image: screenshot]